# Python: While installing module -> parser. No matching distribution found for parser

Tags: python

While installing some modules like 'parser', I am getting this error.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement parser (from versions: )
>    No matching distribution found for parser

Could you please let me whats could be done here.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: windows, linux, anaconda? What commands did you run? Please post complete log, either here or pastebin or whatever. Batteries in my crystal ball is currently somewhat flat...

Comment: On windows, I used **pip install parser** command

Comment: The log is as follow..Collecting parser
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement parser (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for parser

Answer (score 0):

In both Python 2 and 3, `parser` is a built in package. If that's the one you're looking for then you don't need to install it yourself.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html

Comment: I got this error while using this snippet of code -------> from html.parser import HTMLParser  
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from urllib import parse

Comment: @iSampada What is the error you get when running those lines?

Comment: I want to know why does this error occurs, and how to solve this. I frequently get this error while installing modules. [I am new to Python]

Comment: The error in your original post means that the package you're trying to install either doesn't exist or hasn't been released for your combination of OS and Python versions.